# Allow certain contacts to ring when phone on silent/night mode?

Tags: call-screening, silent-mode, oneplus-3, oxygenos

My WinPhone had this feature to set my phone silent at fixed hours of the night, but whitelist certain contacts for calls/texts.

I've recently switched to Android (OnePlus3) and while I'm sure this must be possible (iOS does it too IIRC) I can't see what its called or where to configure it.

Can someone tell me what these features are called on Android?

My phone is running OxygenOS 3.2.8 atop of Android 6.0.1

Comment: Which version of Android? See settings>about phone and you will likely see something like 6.0.1(guessing since it's a a new model), that's Marshmallow. In that case, you have a *Priority Mode orDo Not disturb* (settings>sound and notifications>do not disturb,) where you can your own rules.

Comment: @beeshyams sorry yes my phone is running OxygenOS 3.2.8 atop of Android 6.0.1. The settings app is pretty awful though I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Priority mode (Android 5.0 and higher) : http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-android-priority-mode-get-back-silent-mode/

Comment: I can't find those settings. The 1+3 has a hardware slider normal/priority/silent and the settings I see are different. Anyway I don't want to stop most calls in priority... I want to allow a few contacts to break through silent

Comment: In Priority only starred contacts will be notified, rest will be in silent only

Comment: Yes, i clean forgot about that hardware slider - [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/oneplus-has-absolutely-spoiled-me-every-android-should-have-alert-slider), a random Google pick shows how you can use it, I am sure there would be you tube videos as well.  From what I read here, those contacts whom you wish to permit calling should be *starred* callers as @samnaction mentioned

Comment: what about android 7? i don't see a do not disturb on my htc one

Answer (score 27):

look at your settings for **Do not disturb** mode.
it will make your phone silent for everything, except your favorites contacts.

Comment: Will this work even if the ring volume is set to zero?

Comment: what about alarms? there is no way I can explicitly put an exception for alarms

Comment: I have verified that alarms work with do not disturb mode

Answer (score 4):

Look in sounds and vibrations. Scroll to the bottom. There should be a do not disturb setting. In there you will find allow exceptions. Customize to you're preferred settings

Comment: This does not work when the phone is on vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

"Silent" mode is sometimes conflated with Do-not-disturb mode, but they are different. Under standard Android, you can set certain contacts as able to bypass the DND mode. But if the phone is on silent (volume set to zero), then you still won't hear the call.

If you need a certain contact to be able to call you, audibly, even when the phone is on DND and silent, you can do this:

1. Add the contact to the DND exemptions.
2. Install an app such as MacroDroid. Create a macro so that whan that person calls, the volume is set to 100%.